# What happens when a manifested creature dies?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent made me manifest a Sorcery card using [Reality Shift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reality%20Shift). Later that creature died. Should it stay manifested in the graveyard? Should I put it back in my library instead of the graveyard?

Comment: Was the card [Reality Shift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=554178)?

Comment: Yes  and the card wasnt a creature it was a sorcery he turned into a 2/2

Comment: I have edited the question to ask about the specific mechanic (manifest) used on that card. If it does not capture the original intent of the question, feel free to change it.

Comment: As a note for your original wording, being face down does not make a card a token, a token is specifically defined as an object that is not a card.

Answer (score 5):

**The manifested card goes to the graveyard face up after it dies.**

First, a manifested card is just a face down card. It does not become a token, but there is a [placeholder token](https://scryfall.com/card/tfrf/4/manifest) that can be put on top of it to help remember that it is a manifested creature. It is just a memory aid, and does not actually change anything about the creature.

If a permanent dies, it goes to the graveyard. This isn't different for face down permanents. Cards can only be face up in the graveyard, so the manifested card turns face up as it goes to the graveyard.